# Different number of columns per row

Tags: html, css

[Correct Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjwLq.jpg)Instead of 3 columns per row (as below), i want to display the first 2 rows with 3 columns and then the 3rd row with 5 columns and 4th row with 4 columns (changing CSS only)

CSS
`ul { columns: 3; }`

HTML
`<ul class="list"> <li><a href="#">1</a></li> <li><a href="#">2</a></li> <li><a href="#">3</a></li> <li><a href="#">4</a></li> <li><a href="#">5</a></li> <li><a href="#">6</a></li> <li><a href="#">7</a></li> <li><a href="#">8</a></li> <li><a href="#">9</a></li> <li><a href="#">10</a></li> <li><a href="#">11</a></li> <li><a href="#">12</a></li> <li><a href="#">13</a></li> <li><a href="#">14</a></li> <li><a href="#">15</a></li> </ul> </body>`

I can't figure out how to change the number of columns per row.

Comment: Please read [ask] and create [mre]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use css `grid` model and change the column number with `grid-column`. This uses some kind of trick though. To achieve this, we can set the original column to be 60, then we can `span` the first 6 elements (first and second row) to `20`, then we `span` the 7th to 11th elements to `12`, finally we `span` the rest of the elements to `15`.

How did we choose those values? we can basically get the LCM of 3, 4, 5 which is 60, then we can divide 60 to each number of column: `60 / 3 = 20`, `60 / 5 = 12`, `60 / 4 = 15`.

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(60, 1fr);
}

li:nth-child(-n+6) {
  grid-column: span 20;
}

li:nth-child(n+7):nth-child(-n+11) {
  grid-column: span 12;
}

li:nth-child(n+12) {
  grid-column: span 15;
}

/* just for styling */

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">13</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">15</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want to make it exactly as your image though, you can just simply use add `grid-column: 1` on each of the starting row:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(4), li:nth-child(7), li:nth-child(12) {
  grid-column: 1;
}

/* just for styling */

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">13</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">15</a></li>
</ul>
```